# C# - Get most common string in a Model list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to get the most common string from a model list using Linq, but I don't really know how.

Here is some example code:

```
public ModelClass {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int num { get; set; }
}
```

Imagine a huge listof ModelClass is stored in the database

```
// in some controller
var model = from s in _db.SomeClass
            select s;

string mostCommonName = ???????
```

How would I find the most common name from this list using linq?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy()` to help find strings with the same value

```
var mostCommonName = _db.SomeClass
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(x => new 
    { 
        Name = x.Key,
        Count = x.Count()
    })  
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
    .Select(x => x.Name)
    .First();
```

Comment: not sure ,just asking,dont we need to perform ordinal comparision?

Comment: You may also use `ToLower()` (if case is not sensitive) to return proper results.

Comment: Hi, this looks like the right answer. Can't really get it to work though, because I get the error `cannot convert source '{Key:string, Count:int}' to target type 'string'` if I set `mostCommonName` as a string and not a var. What to do?

Comment: @Rockyy i've added a `Select()` to return just the string value instead of the Name and Count anonymous type. You could also do `First().Name`

Comment: Great! Thanks! I should have been able to figure that out myself :P

Answer (score 1):

```
    var query = from n in  _db.SomeClass
                group n by n.name into grouped
                select new
                {
                    name = grouped.First().name,
                    count = grouped.Count(),
                } into result
                orderby result.count descending
                select result;

    string mostCommonName = query.First().name;
```